# How do I get the response associated with a specific GET request in playwright python?

Tags: python, playwright, playwright-python

I want to get the response associated with a GET request. I am using playwright python. I haven't been able to find anything on the internet to solve my problem, which is making me wonder if my understanding of this is flawed. I have a specific GET request whose JSON response is what I am trying to get. The reason why I am using playwright is because I want to trigger the GET requests, which happens when certain elements are clicked or when the page is scrolled.

I can view the GET request and its JSON response in the browser inspector's Network tab, I can also make the request using insomnia and get the response but I don't know how to go about it in playwright. Do I have to remake the request and get the response that way? It seems kinda inconvenient as there has to be a way to get the response, as I am able to display the GET, POST requests and their responses in the terminal using:

```
page.on("request", lambda request: print(">>", request.method, request.url))
page.on("response", lambda response: print("<<", response.status, response.url))
```

But I don't know what response is associated with the request as, in the browser inspector, you can simply click on the request and view its response. I would do it using the python requests library but that would be very inconvenient considering what I am trying to do next: use playwright to trigger multiple GET requests and get their JSON responses.

I know the GET request URL, and would like to get the the response to that specific request only.

I am new to playwright and programming overall and would appreciate it if you could as much as nudge me in the right direction. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my understanding, this might solve your problem: Example of catching the search request on the Playwright homepage and print the response:

Update: added how to return raw json.

```py
from playwright.sync_api import Page
import json


def test_catchSearchResponse(page: Page):
    # Goto playwright homepage and press search box:
    page.goto("https://playwright.dev/")
    page.get_by_role('button', name='Search').click()

    # Catching response associated with filling searchfield:
    with page.expect_response("**.algolia.net/**") as response:

        # Fill a letter in searchbox to trigger the post-request:
        page.get_by_placeholder('Search docs').fill('A')

        # Printing the value of the response as a python json object:
        print(response.value.json())

        # Printing the value of the response as raw json:
        print(json.dumps(response.value.json()))
```

More about it [in the docs](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/network#network-events)

Comment: I'll try this and let you know how it went. Hopefully it works because I really want it to.

Comment: Thanks for this, it worked but, unfortunately, it returns a broken JSON response – messes up the quotation marks, rendering it unable to be parsed. I think it's returning a truncated response.

Comment: Okay so the response wasn't truncated or anything, it was returning it with single quotes and I had to covert it into JSON before attempting to parse it – which is weird because json() should return: JSON.  I will be marking it as a solution.

Comment: .json() returns a python object represented as a json file. I have updated my answer with how to get a raw json.

Answer (score 0):

The response class has a [request](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/api/class-response#response-request) object. So you can get the request from a response.

Comment: But I wanna do the opposite. I wanna get the response associated with the request.

Comment: The request object from the response will be the same object you will get in the request event. You can capture the request object in the request event and then compare it to the request object of a response

Comment: You can't do that early in the pipe because a request in the request event doesn't have a response yet.

Comment: ahh I understand. I'll try it and let you know.